# SCIPY minimization using L-BFGS_B, error "TOTAL NO. of f AND g EVALUATIONS EXCEEDS LIMIT"

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize-minimize

Trying to optimize one function using scipy minimize using [L-BFGS-B method](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.minimize-lbfgsb.html)

I have a simple code snippet to catch some errors and messages from minimize function:

```
result = minimize(fun = res_fit_obj_f, 
                          x0 = input_params_initial_guess, 
                          args = (all_fitted_windows_df, 
                                  ...
                                  debug), 
                          method = method, 
                          bounds = input_params_bounds,
                          options = options
                          )
        

        # Check if the optimization was successful
        if result.success:

            success = True
            xopt = result.x
            fopt = result.fun

            benefit = result.fun - ig_obj_f_val

            rel_benefit = np.round(benefit / ig_obj_f_val * 100 , 2)

        else:
            success = False

            # Print an error message if the optimization was not successful
            print('Warning!')
            print('SCIPY Minimization Error (used method =',method,') failed.  Error message:', result.message)
```

Now I have the next message in some cases:

**STOP: TOTAL NO. of f AND g EVALUATIONS EXCEEDS LIMIT.**

When I have tuned previously in options for SCIPY L-BFGS-B:

```
hps['options'] = {
    'maxiter': 1000000,
    'disp' : hps['debug'], # to display convergence messages
    'maxls': 200,
    'ftol': 1e-10,
    'gtol': 1e-10,
}
```

For the time of calculation I don't think that in this case solver made 1000000 iterations, so it's strange that it gave that message.

1. How can I check the history of iterations in this case?
2. How can I increase the allowed number of function evaluations to give the optimizer more time/effort to get the most accurate solution?

Answer (score 0):

The number of L-BFGS-B iterations is different to the total number of function evaluations. There will be several function evaluations per iteration.

In order to increase the total number of function evaluations you need to supply the `maxfun` keyword in `options`. Please see the documentation at https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.minimize-lbfgsb.html#optimize-minimize-lbfgsb